# Give access to Git repository with no ability to merge back

Tags: git

I have a `test_project` git repository on an AWS - I'm not using github.

I want several students to be able to "checkout", "branch", "clone", whatever so they can get all the files available in the project but never be able to "check in", "merge", "push", whatever back into the original `test_project`.

When I pull projects down I always `clone` it to my personal machines so I can make changes anywhere and `push` them before I leave that machine - this way I always have the most recent version of whatever I'm working on (I have 3 machines I'm constantly having to work between).

What commands should I have the students use to "checkout" this project so they can't accidentally "merge" their changes back to the original repository?

Comment: +1 for teaching students to use a vcm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give access via git:// or https:// protocol. Don't give them write-access (e.g. via ssh://). If it's a small repository, dumb http:// might just do fine as well.

Comment: @Rico: It's not all that difficult. For git:// style access, you only need to start git-daemon for the repository in question. For http(s):// access it involves a little bit more configuration (e.g. apache)

Comment: I'm planning to host a website on this server anyway so I'm going to have to learn how to configure apache anyway.  I may as well go this route when I'm ready.

Answer (score 1):

See "Enforcing a User-Based ACL System" in the article [Customizing Git - An Example Git-Enforced Policy](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-4.html) which explains how to set it up through hooks on the receiving end.

[gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite#readme) seems to be a better alternative when your environment has grown a bit.